# android - how to run some code after the "power button" is pushed

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have an app that plays some music file while the application is open but when i press the power button the sound keeps playing for some reason. Is there a way to override the power button so it will also stop the media player when pushed ?

```
MediaPlayer mp;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
...
mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, mAudio[0]);
mp.start();
...
...
}
```

I would like to call `mp.stop()` when the power button is pressed.

Comment: Could you please specify how you play sound? In service, in activity? Could you please show your code, don't be so shy ;)

Answer (score 1):

Override [`onKeyDown`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.Callback.html#onKeyDown(int,%20android.view.KeyEvent)) and check if it's `KEYCODE_POWER`.

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER) {
        // Stop the media player here
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: @merstik sorry but it seems there is not such options, KEYCODE_WAKEUP won't work if the device is already awake. But try once.

Answer (score 0):

Add this method:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER) {
        // stop the media from playing
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

This method is being activated when a key is being pressed. It checks what key is pressed and reacts for it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to understand, when you want to pause or stop the sound. If you want to do it, when you **exit/hide** an application, then overriding `onKeyDown` won't help. I think better approach in this case will be:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle onSaveInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(onSaveInstanceState);
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, mAudio[0]);
}

protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mp.start();
}

protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mp.stop();
}
```

But if you want to stop your sound only when Power button is pressed, then yes, you need to override `onKeyDown`